# Как определить относительный и абсолютный путь в теге SRC?

Tags: php

Как определить относительный и абсолютный путь в теге SRC изображения?
Суть в том, что если src имеет вид: `../photo.jpg, /photo.jpg photo.jpg`, то дописать полный адрес http://

Comment: Путь узнать несложно, но смысла я не вижу, и как ты собрался их все заменить, я тоже понять не могу.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, насколько понимаю, достаточно проверить строку на наличие `http` или `//` в начале.

@Bastian, при парсинге сайтов такое необходимо для вытягивания изображений.

Comment: https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/phpuri

Comment: А без http:// картинка может отобразится с www? Или без www?